# JsTree with JSON stuck on loading

Tags: json, jstree

I am using JSON to display a JsTree. The JSON is being built up as a string via a recursive function. Now I went through a few tests with smaller/less complicated trees and got it to work. I used JSONLint to check for valid JSON and eventually got the correct syntax. Now when I try and display the intended big tree its just stuck with the loading .gif (which used to be because the JSON was incorrect) but after checking it on JSONLint it was correct.

Any possible causes for this? I doubt the tree could be too big or anything.

Recursive Function:

```
public void getViewTree(ref string tree, Int32? id = null)
        {
            var topNodes = (from items in db.AssessmentViewItems
                           select items).Take(1);

            #region getChildren via LINQ
            if (id == null)
            {
                topNodes = from items in db.AssessmentViewItems
                           where items.ParentAssessmentViewItemID == null
                           && items.AssessmentViewID == 17
                           select items;
            }
            else
            {

                topNodes = from items in db.AssessmentViewItems
                           where items.ParentAssessmentViewItemID == id
                           && items.AssessmentViewID == 17
                           select items;
            } 
            #endregion

            int counter = 1;
            int max = (int)topNodes.Count();
            foreach (var node in topNodes)
            {

                if (node.ParentAssessmentViewItemID == null)
                {
                    {\"id\":\"532topNode\",\"selected\":true},\"children\":[null,
                    tree += "{\"data\":\"" + node.Title.Trim().Replace("\"","").Replace("("," ").Replace(":"," ").Replace("-"," ").Replace("&","and").Replace("/"," ").Replace("\\"," ").Replace(","," ").Replace("•", " ") + "\",\"attr\":{\"id\":\"" + node.AssessmentViewItemID + "\", \"selected\":true}, \"children\":[";   

                    getViewTree(ref tree, node.AssessmentViewItemID);
                    tree += "}]";
                    if (counter < max)
                    {
                        tree += "},";
                    }
                }
                else if (node.Type.Equals("Legal Topic"))
                {
                    tree += "{\"data\":\"" + node.Title.Trim().Replace("\"", "").Replace("(", " ").Replace(":", " ").Replace("-", " ").Replace("&", "and").Replace("/", " ").Replace("\\", " ").Replace(",", " ").Replace("•", " ") + "\",\"attr\":{\"id\":\"" + node.AssessmentViewItemID + "\", \"selected\":true}";

                    if (counter < max)
                    {
                        tree += "},";
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    var topNodes1 = from items in db.AssessmentViewItems
                               where items.ParentAssessmentViewItemID == node.AssessmentViewItemID
                               && items.AssessmentViewID == 17
                               select items;

                    if (topNodes1.Count() > 0)
                    {

                        tree += "{\"data\":\"" + node.Title.Trim().Replace("\"", "").Replace("(", " ").Replace(":", " ").Replace("-", " ").Replace("&", "and").Replace("/", " ").Replace("\\", " ").Replace(",", " ").Replace("•", " ") + "\",\"attr\":{\"id\":\"" + node.AssessmentViewItemID + "\", \"selected\":true}, \"children\":[";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tree += "{\"data\":\"" + node.Title.Trim().Replace("\"", "").Replace("(", " ").Replace(":", " ").Replace("-", " ").Replace("&", "and").Replace("/", " ").Replace("\\", " ").Replace(",", " ").Replace("•", " ") + "\",\"attr\":{\"id\":\"" + node.AssessmentViewItemID + "\", \"selected\":true}";
                    }

                    getViewTree(ref tree, node.AssessmentViewItemID);

                    if (topNodes1.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        tree += "}]";
                    }

                    if (counter < max)
                    {
                        tree += "}";
                        tree += ",";
                    }

                }

                counter++;
            }
        }
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#demoTree").jstree({
        "json_data": {
            "data": treeModel
        },
        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"],

    });
});
```

Calling Recursive Function:

```
string tree = "[";

getViewTree(ref tree);

tree += "}]";

return View("About", "_Layout", tree);
```

After using Chrome Dev Tools, the error that I get from it:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL (program):54
Uncaught Neither data nor ajax settings supplied.

I did check it for syntax on JSONLint. Small tree is generated fine without those 2 errors

Comment: any code to get started with? what error do you get?

Comment: No error, there is just the loading .gif. I could give you the JSON generated if that helps?

Comment: I added my code onto first post.

Comment: How many nodes is in the tree? Have you tried ajax load?

Comment: seems like there is about +-400 nodes in the tree. No I have not tried AJAX load, not entirely sure how it works too be honest.

Comment: If you'll use chrome's developer tool at the network tab while the page is loading you will see the error.

Comment: Ok, I found the dev tools and the error were:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL (program):54
Uncaught Neither data nor ajax settings supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem got solved by using DevExpress tree. Exact same JSON string.